# Ошибка: One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: photos_list is invalid

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: photos_list is invalid]

Как же решить это чудо, когда `['photo']` пустой? Я долго не мог понять, как же работает эта штукенция..

Этот вопрос создан с таким названием для корректного "поиска" именно этой ошибки!

Comment: Так может и передавать нужно параметр `photos_list`, а не `photo`?

Answer (score 0):

Основная функция method - это запрос на выполнение нашего метода!

```
def method(method, values):
    values["access_token"] = 'Токен группы'
    values["v"] = 'Версия api (Находится в настройках api в вк)'
    try:
        query = requests.post('https://api.vk.com/method/' + method, params=values)
        return query
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
```

Эта функция является загрузкой фотографии в сообщение вк.

```
 def upload_on_server_photo(filename):
    #Для ботов/массовых рассылок с токеном сообщества можно указать peer_id=0.
    #Изображение будет загружено в скрытый альбом группы.
    values = {'peer_id': 0}
    #Просим у вк специальную ссылку для отправки по ней фотографии
    upload_url = method('photos.getMessagesUploadServer', values).json()["response"]["upload_url"]
    #Ключ обязательно должен быть 'photo'
    #filename может принять как путь с файлом так и сам файл, если он лежит в дериктории с запускаемым файлом .py
    #filename = 'root//vk_bot//screen.png'
    #filename = 'screen.png'
    values = {'photo': open(filename, 'rb')}
    #Делаем запрос по специальной ссылке upload_url для загрузки файла filename
    info_load = requests.post(upload_url, files=values).json()
    #Для сохранения вк просит ввести все данные, что пришли после загрузки (Для сохранения)
    values = {
        'photo': info_load["photo"],
        'server': info_load["server"],
        'hash': info_load["hash"]
    }
    #Создаём запрос о том, что мы хотим сохранить нашу фотографию!
    info_photo = method('photos.saveMessagesPhoto', values).json()["response"][0]
    #Мы получаем информацию о нашей фотографии
    #Строчку из return мы уже можем отправить)
    #'attachment': f'photo{info_photo["owner_id"]}_{info_photo["id"]}'
    return f'photo{info_photo["owner_id"]}_{info_photo["id"]}'
```